# jsonGenerator cannot pass strings with whitespace

Tags: java, javascript, html, json

Hi i have a problem i cannot pass a string value containning whitespaces to the js function, im using jsonGenerator, here is my code:

```
jGenerator.writeStringField(cols[8],ap.getContentId() != null ? "<img src='img/active.png' onclick=authorizeContent("+ap.getContentId()+","+ ap.getName()+"); style='cursor:pointer;margin:0px 5px;width:18px;height:18px;'/>  <img src='img/delete.png' onclick=authorizeContent('"+ ap.getContentId() +"','"+ ap.getName()+"'); style='cursor:pointer;margin:0px 5px;width:18px;height:18px;'/>" : "");
```

This is the generated HTML

```
<td class="center"><img src="img/active.png" onclick="authorizeContent(47,la" diabla);="" style="cursor:pointer;margin:0px 5px;width:18px;height:18px;">  <img src="img/delete.png" onclick="authorizeContent('47','la" diabla');="" style="cursor:pointer;margin:0px 5px;width:18px;height:18px;"></td>
```

Please help, i also tried this other way but didnt worked:

```
        jGenerator.writeStringField(cols[8],ap.getContentId() != null ? "<img src='img/active.png' onclick=authorizeContent('"+ ap.getContentId() +"','"+ ap.getName()+"'); style='cursor:pointer;margin:0px 5px;width:18px;height:18px;'/>  <img src='img/delete.png' onclick=authorizeContent('"+ ap.getContentId() +"','"+ ap.getName()+"'); style='cursor:pointer;margin:0px 5px;width:18px;height:18px;'/>" : "");
```

and the html

```
<td class="center"><img src="img/active.png" onclick="authorizeContent('47','la" diabla');="" style="cursor:pointer;margin:0px 5px;width:18px;height:18px;">  <img src="img/delete.png" onclick="authorizeContent('47','la" diabla');="" style="cursor:pointer;margin:0px 5px;width:18px;height:18px;"></td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed using this way:

```
        jGenerator.writeStringField(cols[8],"<img onclick=\"authorizeContent('"+ ap.getContentId() +"','"+ ap.getName().trim() +"');\" style=\"cursor:pointer;margin:0px 5px;width:18px;height:18px;\" src=\"img/active.png\" /> <img onclick=\"authorizeContent('"+ ap.getContentId() +"','"+ ap.getName().trim() +"');\" style=\"cursor:pointer;margin:0px 5px;width:18px;height:18px;\" src=\"img/delete.png\" />");
```